# PrimitiveMatrixQ?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, expression-test

Is there a simple way to test in Mathematica whether a non-negative square matrix $A$ is primitive?

**Primitive** means that for some positive integer power $k$, all entries of $A^k$ (matrix power) are positive.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://doi.org/10.2307/3212514)?

Comment: @J.M. Bingo! I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
primitiveQ1 = MarkovProcessProperties[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, #], "Primitive"] &
```

Alternatively,

```
primitiveQ2 = RandomProcesses`MarkovChainDump`PrimitiveStochasticMatrixQ
```

This works in both version 9 and version 11 provided `DiscreteMarkovProcess` is run before it is used (thanks: @ChrisK).

In case it doesn't work even after invoking `DiscreteMarkovProcess` first,the following is its implementation (after replacing intermediate function calls):

```
primitiveQ2[m_] := With[{n = Length[m]}, 
  MatchQ[SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[m], {{__Integer}}] && 
 (Tr[m] > 0 || Min[MatrixPower[m, n (n - 2) + 2]] > 0)]
```

Examples:

```
mat1 = {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
mat2 = {{0, 1/3, 0, 2/3, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/2, 0}, 
  {1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 0}, {1/3, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/3}};

primitiveQ1 /@ {mat1, mat2}
```

> {False, True}

```
primitiveQ2 /@ {mat1, mat2}
```

> {False, True}

Comment: I don't have this package. Where can I find it?

Comment: @becko, it comes built-in in version 9.

Comment: It's no longer there in v11.1

Comment: @becko, I added its implementation  which works in version 11.

Comment: @kglr Your first version works for me in v11.2, after running `DiscreteMarkovProcess` first.

Comment: @ChrisK, thank you, this is interesting. It seems that there is some background initialization needed. None of the ``MarkovProcesses`MarkovChainDump`*`` stuff showed up when I tried yesterday.  Perhaps I should have posted `primitiveQ`  after `primitiveQ2`:) ... Actually, the same initialization is need in version 9: In a fresh kernel it doesn't work without using `DiscreteMarkovProcess` first.